# Android sending JsonObject with json array

Tags: android

I need to post one request to server. 
Format i need to send is : { “userId”: , “array”: ("A,"b","c",...) }

I can send the jsonobject but i don't know how to send JsonObejct and Jsonarray together in one request.

Comment: So what is your problem? Are you not able to create a JSON string with JSONObject and JSONArray.

Comment: Yes Lalit..I want to send data in the above format. but not able to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice [JSON Encoding Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples) refer this.

Comment: Nice Lalit..very nice link..Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Is it that easy how I think?

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

for (String string : new String [] {"A", "b", "c", ...}) {
    array.put(string);
}

json.put("userId", theId);
json.put("array", array);
sendYourRequest(json);

// This is wrong! Code corrected. Thank you for the Feedback!!!
// json.put("array", new String [] {"A", "b", "c", ...});
```

Comment: That's a great comment... ;-) You should provide your code. Show us what you want to do. Show us what is not working. You're the one with the question and the code in front of you, we're good, but we can't read your mind ;-)

Comment: This does not work.  It fails as it doesn't generate a valid json array.  In my debugger I see "array":"[Ljava.lang.String;@40551ce8"

Comment: @JamesBaca Thank you! Now I see why the previous complaint. I corrected my answer. Thank you for your accurate feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a JSONObject and a JSONArrayObject.  Add all the items you want in your json array.  Then add the json array into the JsonObject.  See below:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("1st array item");
array.put("2nd array item");

JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();       
holder.put("array", array);
holder.put("other_params", ...);
```

Then you can also verify that the json looks valid by doing the following:

```
String jsonString = holder.toString(); //verify that the json is in the correct format
```